# encrypt in Java and Decrypt in SQL the same data with AES

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption, cryptography

Am trying to insert some value through JAVA Application with AES Algorithm and need to decrypt the same data from the SQL Procedure and need to process that data.

Which is the best practice to do so?

Comment: As you are using two different systems you cannot rely on system defaults.  You _must_ explicitly specify everything.  Obvious things like key, IV, mode as well as the less obvious like character encoding.  Any mismatch will likely cause a failure as crypto is designed to fail in the case of any mismatch.

Comment: Is it advisable to send that data to a procedure and encrypt within the SQL and store it in Table and Decrypt it later from the table for my purpose? @roosum